# How to focus on main page input elment when there is a non modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, focus, non-modal

My case is under condition: The non modal dialog has input inside, and it doesn't close when clicking outside

When the non modal dialog is open, I cannot focus on input in main page. When I clicking on input in main page, the focus jumps to the first input in the dialog

I tried mainPageInput.focus() not working. Also I tried dialogInput.blur() first then mainPageInput.focus() still not working

their tabIndex are "0" as default

Comment: Please provide some code?

Comment: HTML: 
 <input></input>
<button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>

JS:
require(['dijit/Dialog'], function(Dialog) {
    myDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px",
        class: "nonModal"
    });
});

CSS:
.nonModal_underlay {
    display:none;
}

Comment: I will try to upload a jsfiddler here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/elichen2017/x3jmpqk6/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the Tabindex to = -1, it has been work with my browser/code.
Just try to adjust the tabindex below 0.